# Generating .pem from AWS ACM Certificate

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-certificate-manager

I intend on using an AWS Certificate Manager (ACM)-generated SSL certificate on my load balancer (in front of a Node.js app cluster). The APIs would be in turn called by an iOS app, for which I would apparently need to put in my resources as a .der file.

However, to convert to a .der (using the command `openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in cert.pem -out cert.der`), I need the corresponding .pem file for the certificate. How do I go about generating the same? I couldn't find anything in the ACM documentation to help with the same....

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer!

Need to attach ACM policy to the instance IAM role, and then run:

```
aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn ACM-CERTIFICATE-ARN --region ACM-CERTIFICATE-REGION
```

This would generate the certificate chain and the certificate. Take the certificate first, and then the chain, and copy into a .pem. We'll need to remove the \n and fold the length of the file to only be a max of 64 chars.

Finally, run the command I pasted earlier above, i.e. `openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in cert.pem -out cert.der`. That would generate the .der file which we can now integrate in the iOS bundle!